# Selenium Dynamic Selectors for WebElements

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, dynamic

I am building a testing framework, my objective is to test many websites that have similar pages with light difference between each other using this framework.

I have an issue where I want WebElements Selectors to be dynamic, which means that I want to pass the way I want to find the element as a parameter to FindElement method.

I am trying to build something like this:

```
public class WebComponent
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public IWebElement WebElement{get;set;}
            public Accessor Accessor { get; set; }
            public WebComponent()
            {
                Accessor = new Accessor();
            }

    }
    public class Accessor
    {
        OpenQA.Selenium.By By { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

And  later in my code when I want to have instance of this class:

```
WebComponent component = new WebComponent();
component.ID = 1;
component.Name = "Logout Button";
component.Description = "The button to click when user wants to logout of website";
component.Accessor.By = By.Id;
component.Accessor.Value = "logout";
component.WebElement = Browser.Driver.FindElement(//missing code);
```

My question is how can I find the WebElement using component.Accessor, any advice or suggested edits will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`By.Id` is a method group, you can't assign it to type `OpenQA.Selenium.By`. The assignment should be

```
component.Accessor.By = By.id("logout"); // or any other By and value.
```

And then you can locate the element using

```
component.WebElement = Browser.Driver.FindElement(component.Accessor.By);
```

> Edit

To choose the locator and value dynamically you can do something like

```
private By chooseType(String locatorType, string value) {
    switch(locatorType) {
        case "id":
            return By.id(value);
        case "class":
            return By.className(value);
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: but this way will not allow me to have dynamic access method which might change between {Id, Name, ClassName, etc..}

Comment: @YahyaHHussein Why not? you can do `component.Accessor.By = By.Id("logout");` and line under `component.Accessor.By = By.className("someClass");`. `Now component.Accessor.By` is `By.className("someClass");`

Comment: Think like if I want the tester to choose the access method using combobox. this way will require if condition for each access method.

Comment: @YahyaHHussein If you want dynamic locators you have to choose them some how. If you want to avoid `if else` statements you can do the choosing process in method with `switch case` that returns the `By`, Something like `private By chooseType(String locatorType, string value) { switch(locatorType) { case "id": return By.id("logout"); case "class" : return By.className("name");} }`

Comment: Thank you, this helps, please update your answer and add this

Comment: @YahyaHHussein Edited